# When i click an exact link an image should appear with jquery and timeout

Tags: jquery, image, timeout, onclick, fade

what do i need to do beacuse i am new to jquery is the following:
I want: when the user clicks an exact link. An exact image should appear in the middle of the screen with a fade effect or without (whatever easier) and then it will disappear after 4 seconds.

In the head i included this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

In the Body i included this:
      `<a href="#" id="myLink">click</a>
      <img src="achievement.png" id="myImage" style="display:none">`

i figured it out, now how do i set it to overlay over the content of the website? CSS probably

Comment: Post some code and we will definitely help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(){
    $('#myImage').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();
});
```

Here is a good way to center an image on the screen using css:

html:

`<div id="myImage"></div>`

css:

```
#myImage{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background: url(path/to/image.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

note that I'm using a <div> tag with a background image instead of a <img> tag. This is much easier to center using css.

Comment: where #myLink goes the link and where #myImage goes the image link?

Comment: Yes, myLink is the id of the link, and myImage is the id of the image. The hash character (#) specifies that jQuery should search for an id.

Comment: ok i figured it out as i give an example on my edited question. The final question i have is:For constructing the css to center in the middle of the window and overlay the content, i have to place the image into a div and then construct the css for that div?

Comment: I have updated the answer, with an example on how to center an image.

Comment: ok i made it work, using style="display:none" thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) plugin to show the image in a modal easily and this plugin has many other features. The code you need to close the colorbox automatically after `4 sec` is as follows

```
   $('.colorbox').colorbox({
        onOpen: function(){
           window.setTimeout(function() {
             $.colorbox.close();
          }, 4000);
        }
    });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/jfFrt/)

Comment: thank your for the reply, what i actually try to do is like an achievement appearance: For example: Download <== link  onclick show the achievement image then fadeout.